# alertdialog take too long to dismiss

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, picasso, wallpapermanager

an alert dialog is taking too long to dismiss and I don't why it's happening.
when I click on any item on alert dialog my app gets freeze and responds and after a few seconds. Alert dialog does not dismiss fastly.
the URL of the images comes from the firebase database.
I am coding in API 28

setwallpaper is an activity with only one image view

setwallpaper.java

```
public class setwallpaper extends AppCompatActivity{


    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE =1000 ;
   // DrawerLayout drawer;
    //Button btn_set,btn_download;
    ImageView imageView_set;
    int index;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    //WeakReference<ContentResolver> contentResolverWeakReference ;


    //ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);



      //  contentResolverWeakReference = new WeakReference<ContentResolver>(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver());

        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            {
                if (grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


                break;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setwallpaper);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


            },PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }


       // Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //final NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView_set=findViewById(R.id.imageview_set);

        Intent intent=new Intent();
        //String url=intent.getStringExtra("url");
            int postion=getIntent().getIntExtra("url",0);
            index=postion;
        Picasso.get().load(array_class.arrayurl.get(postion).getImage()).into(imageView_set);



        imageView_set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               // WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(setwallpaper.this);

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(setwallpaper.this);
                builder.setTitle("Title");
                builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                                {"set homescreen", "set lockscreen", "download"},
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                                // of the selected item
                                switch (which) {
                                    case 0:

                                        setimage();
                                        //Toast.makeText(setwallpaper.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        setlockimage();
                                        Toast.makeText(setwallpaper.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    case 2:

                                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(setwallpaper.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                                            Toast.makeText(setwallpaper.this, "you should grant permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            requestPermissions(new String[]{

                                                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


                                            },PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                            return;
                                        }else {

                                            final String filename= UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg";

                                            Picasso.get().load(array_class.arrayurl.get(index).getImage()).into(new settingimagehelper(setwallpaper.this,
                                                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                                                    ,filename,"image desc"));
                                        }
                                        Toast.makeText(setwallpaper.this, "downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;

                                }
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();


            }
        });



        setResult(RESULT_OK);

    }




private void setimage() {



        Picasso.get()
                .load(array_class.arrayurl.get(index).getImage())
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
                        /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Set it in the ImageView
                        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(setwallpaper.this);
                        try {
                            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(setwallpaper.this, "wallpaper set as background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    }
```